# Simple way to display an object (POCO) in an ASPX file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, webforms

First of all, let me start by saying that I'm not an ASP.NET developer. I have web experience with other technologies but have only read about webforms. I generally know what they do but have no experience with them.

And now my problem. I have inherited a webforms application that has run unmodified for years (~ 6 years) and now I have to enhance it. It's not something complicated, I managed to do about 80% of it but I'am stuck on a thing that seems minor but have not yet found a simple way to achieve it.

I have a simple object, instance of class like this:

```
public class EventDetails
{
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string EventLocation { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    //... etc
}
```

I have created this in `EventDetails.aspx.cs` and need to display it in the `EventDetails.aspx` file and I don't know how. I have read some tutorials and they use `<asp:GridView>` or a list view or a repeater. These have a datasource that they are bind to. I can't use the object directly as a datasource, seems I need to create myself a `IDataSource` etc.

It all seems complicated. I just need to display the thing, nothing else and don't know how. It must be simple, but as I said I have no experience with this.

What is a simple way to display a plain object in an ASPX file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `public` property in your code-behind of type `EventDetails`:

**Code-Behind:**

```
public partial class YourAspxPage : Page {

    public EventDetails EventDetails { get; set; }


    /* ... */
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<span><%= EventDetails.EventName %></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put some user controls, like text boxes in the page. And then, in the page_load event, you do things like:

```
this.someTextBox.Text = eventDetailsInstance.EventName;
```

If you want the user input to be persisted, though, you should learn about databinding, so that you can make an object datasource to bind data controls such as FormView to the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You could fill a DataTable with the data and use that as a datasource.